# differential equation solution with DSolve

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic

I have a problem for my work, I need to calculate this diff. equation
I have,

```
r =\sqrt[ rinf + (ro - rinf)*E^((n*ϵ)/((1 - gm) (1 - rinf)) 
  (1 - z^(-3 (1 - gm))))*z^(-3 ((gm - gx)/(1 - rinf)))]
```

And

```
geff = (gm - gx - ϵ*n*z^(-3 (1 - gm)))*rinf/(1 - rinf) (2/(1 + r) - 1) + gx - n
```

And the diff. eq. is:

```
DSolve[{D[ρ[z], z] == -3/z ρ[z]*geff, ρ[1] == ρo}, ρ[z], z]
```

Mathematica can calculate without adding $gx-n$ to $geff$ ($gx -n$ are the last expressions in $geff$), but when I added $gx-n$ to $geff$ a problem happened and only gives me an integral result, Mathematica can not. Please, anybody?

Answer (score 4):

It is surprising that `DSolve` cannot solve the ODE, because

```
int = Integrate[-3/z *geff, z]
(* -(1/(1 + rinf)) rinf (-((n z^(-3 + 3 gm) ϵ)/(-1 + gm)) + 
   3 (gm - gx) Log[z] + 2 Log[1 + rinf + E^((n (z^3 - z^(3 gm)) ϵ)/((-1 + gm) 
(-1 + rinf) z^3)) (-rinf + ro) z^((3 (gm - gx))/(-1 + rinf))]) *)
```

can be performed, and the solution of the ODE then is simply

```
s = ρo Exp[int]/Exp[int /. z -> 1]
```

which can be verified by

```
Simplify[{D[ρ[z], z] == -3/z ρ[z]*geff, ρ[1] == ρo} /. 
    ρ -> Function[z, Evaluate@s]]
(* {True, True} *)
```

Comment: Much more suprising: MMA can solve the generalized problem  `DSolve[{ \[Rho]'[z]/\[Rho][z] == f'[z]  }, \[Rho][z], z] (*{{\[Rho][z] -> E^f[z] C[1]}}*)`

Comment: Thank you so much @bbgodfrey ... But I apologize because I forgot to put the square root of " r " in the first equation. The correct expression is  " r=\sqrt{.....} ". I'm so sorry, can you help me?

Comment: @will.al  I do not believe that ` r=\sqrt{.....}` is syntactically correct.  Do you mean `Sqrt[…..]`?  In any case, I shall see what I can do.

Comment: Hi @bbgodfrey... It is correct, is Sqrt[...]. Thank you.

Comment: @will.al I am not optimistic that `-3/z *geff` can be integrated in general.  Do the parameters have any special values, for instance are some of them integers?

Comment: @bbgodfrey all of parameters are real number, but not complex.